# Best practice for localization and globalization of strings and labels

Tags: javascript, localization, translation, client-side, globalization

I'm a member of a team with more than 20 developers. Each developer works on a separate module (something near 10 modules). In each module we might have at least 50 CRUD forms, which means that we currently have near 500 **add buttons**, **save buttons**, **edit buttons**, etc.

However, because we want to globalized our application, we need to be able to translate texts in our application. For example, everywhere, the word **add** should become **ajouter** for French users.

What we've done till now, is that for each view in UI or Presentation Layer, we have a dictionary of key/value pairs of translations. Then while rendering the view, we translate required texts and strings using this dictionary. However, this approach, we've come to have something near 500 **add** in 500 dictionaries. This means that we've breached DRY principal.

On the other hand, if we centralize common strings, like putting **add** in one place, and ask developers to use it everywhere, we encounter the problem of not being sure if a string is already defined in the centralized dictionary or not.

One other options might be to have no translation dictionary and use online translation services like Google Translate, Bing Translator, etc.

Another problem that we've encountered is that some developers under the stress of delivering the project on-time can't remember the **translation keys**. For example, for the text of the add button, a developer has used **add** while another developer has used **new**, etc.

What is the best practice, or most well-known method for globalization and localization of string resources of an application?

Comment: The [talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXS_-JRsB8M) by [Alex Sexton](http://alexsexton.com/) on topic [Client Side Internationalization](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXS_-JRsB8M) from the JS EU conference is a good start.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

As far as I know, there's a good library called `localeplanet` for Localization and Internationalization in JavaScript. Furthermore, I think it's native and has no dependencies to other libraries (e.g. jQuery)

Here's the website of library: http://www.localeplanet.com/

Also look at this article by Mozilla, you can find very good method and algorithms for client-side translation: http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2011/10/06/i18njs-internationalize-your-javascript-with-a-little-help-from-json-and-the-server/

The common part of all those articles/libraries is that they use a `i18n` class and a `get` method (in some ways also defining an smaller function name like `_`) for retrieving/converting the `key` to the `value`. In my explaining the `key` means that string you want to translate and the `value` means translated string.
Then, you just need a JSON document to store `key`'s and `value`'s.

For example:

```
var _ = document.webL10n.get;
alert(_('test'));
```

And here the JSON:

```
{ test: "blah blah" }
```

I believe using current popular libraries solutions is a good approach.

Comment: No offense but isn't this what Afshin already tried? He's problem is that different developers have difficulty remembering which keys to use. I agree with that your described method is the way to go. I don't see how it can be otherwise. Thanks for the great links btw.

Answer (score 48):

> When you’re faced with a problem to solve (and frankly, who isn’t
>   these days?), the basic strategy usually taken by we computer people
>   is called “divide and conquer.” It goes like this:
>
> - Conceptualize the specific problem as a set of smaller sub-problems.
> - Solve each smaller problem.
> - Combine the results into a solution of the specific problem.
>
> But “divide and conquer” is not the only possible strategy. We can also take a more generalist approach:
>
> - Conceptualize the specific problem as a special case of a more general problem.
> - Somehow solve the general problem.
> - Adapt the solution of the general problem to the specific problem.
>
> ***- Eric Lippert***

I believe many solutions already exist for this problem in server-side languages such as ASP.Net/C#.

I've outlined some of the major aspects of the problem

- **Issue**: We need to load data only for the desired language

  **Solution**: For this purpose we save data to a separate files for each language

ex. res.de.js, res.fr.js, res.en.js, res.js(for default language)

- Issue: Resource files for each page should be separated so we only get the data we need

  **Solution**: We can use some tools that already exist like
  https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload
- Issue: We need a key/value pair structure to save our data

  **Solution**: I suggest a javascript object instead of string/string air.
  We can benefit from the intellisense from an IDE
- Issue: General members should be stored in a public file and all pages should access them

  **Solution**: For this purpose I make a folder in the root of web application called  Global_Resources and a folder to store global file for each sub folders we named it 'Local_Resources'
- Issue: Each subsystems/subfolders/modules member should override the Global_Resources members on their scope

  **Solution**: I considered a file for each

Application Structure

> ```
> root/
>     Global_Resources/
>         default.js
>         default.fr.js
>     UserManagementSystem/
>         Local_Resources/
>             default.js
>             default.fr.js
>             createUser.js
>         Login.htm
>         CreateUser.htm
> ```

The corresponding code for the files:

**Global_Resources/default.js**

```
var res = {
    Create : "Create",
    Update : "Save Changes",
    Delete : "Delete"
};
```

**Global_Resources/default.fr.js**

```
var res = {
    Create : "créer",
    Update : "Enregistrer les modifications",
    Delete : "effacer"
};
```

The resource file for the desired language should be loaded on the page selected from Global_Resource - This should be the first file that is loaded on all the pages.

**UserManagementSystem/Local_Resources/default.js**

```
res.Name = "Name";
res.UserName = "UserName";
res.Password = "Password";
```

**UserManagementSystem/Local_Resources/default.fr.js**

```
res.Name = "nom";
res.UserName = "Nom d'utilisateur";
res.Password = "Mot de passe";
```

**UserManagementSystem/Local_Resources/createUser.js**

```
// Override res.Create on Global_Resources/default.js
res.Create = "Create User";
```

**UserManagementSystem/Local_Resources/createUser.fr.js**

```
// Override Global_Resources/default.fr.js
res.Create = "Créer un utilisateur";
```

**manager.js file** (this file should be load last)

```
res.lang = "fr";

var globalResourcePath = "Global_Resources";
var resourceFiles = [];

var currentFile = globalResourcePath + "\\default" + res.lang + ".js" ;

if(!IsFileExist(currentFile))
    currentFile = globalResourcePath + "\\default.js" ;
if(!IsFileExist(currentFile)) throw new Exception("File Not Found");

resourceFiles.push(currentFile);

// Push parent folder on folder into folder
foreach(var folder in parent folder of current page)
{
    currentFile = folder + "\\Local_Resource\\default." + res.lang + ".js";

    if(!IsExist(currentFile))
        currentFile = folder + "\\Local_Resource\\default.js";
    if(!IsExist(currentFile)) throw new Exception("File Not Found");

    resourceFiles.push(currentFile);
}

for(int i = 0; i < resourceFiles.length; i++) { Load.js(resourceFiles[i]); }

// Get current page name
var pageNameWithoutExtension = "SomePage";

currentFile = currentPageFolderPath + pageNameWithoutExtension + res.lang + ".js" ;

if(!IsExist(currentFile))
    currentFile = currentPageFolderPath + pageNameWithoutExtension + ".js" ;
if(!IsExist(currentFile)) throw new Exception("File Not Found");
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this approach is that localization and development are tightly coupled... So when an English (whatever default is) string is added the rest of the Languages have to be updated through the code. I'd rather have JSON created with a tool from some type of translations file. Still a good representation!

Comment: have done the same way as you did for localization, you can see that in this query : https://stackoverflow.com/q/53864279/4061006 . The only thing is how you'r translating  Global_Resources/default.js to Global_Resources/default.fr.js  ? 

Which tool/kit are you using to convert those files to desired languages. Since I need this too

Comment: You should store a human-readable comment alongside each key describiting where the string goes and what it means, so that you can provide more context to the translator (or yourself) when you go to add a new language and you've forgotten what some of the strings mean. Do something like `"Create" : {"message": "Create", "description": "text on the button that opens the editor with a blank Foo"}` like they do for [localizing Chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n-messages) for example. Or create a separate file holding these comments.

Answer (score 14):

**jQuery.i18n** is a lightweight jQuery plugin for enabling internationalization in your web pages. It allows you to package custom resource strings in ‘.properties’ files, just like in Java Resource Bundles. It loads and parses resource bundles (.properties) based on provided language or language reported by browser.

to know more about this take a look at the [How to internationalize your pages using JQuery?](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-internationalize-your-pages-using-jquery/)

Comment: The link is gone