# How to do globalization on html5 application that will be converted using phonegap

Tags: html, globalization

I'm used to building globalized application using asp.net (mvc and webform)

But I can't seem to find how to properly build a globalized html5 application that will be converted to android using phonegap.

I tried googling but could not find satisfaction there.

how to you implement globalization in your html5 apps?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html ?

Comment: it's not really what i'm looking for since this is specific to phonegap, i want to build the application as a web site first then convert to android. My question was more general as to what is the best practice to build the globalization module. Should i create .js file that contain the dictionnary strings or should i create the pages in language folder (duplicating files seems like a bad idea)

Comment: Then I think this might helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358817/best-practice-for-localization-and-globalization-of-strings-and-labels