# Localization and globalization file translate tool client side - javascript

Tags: javascript, localization, translation, client-side

I'm a member of a team with more than 20 developers. Each developer works on a separate module. In each module, We load data only for the desired language.
For this purpose we save data to a separate files for each language.

> Example Module 1:
>
> ```
> locale (root folder)
>
>     en
>         en.js
>     pt
>         pt.js
>     fr 
>         fr.js
> ```

en.js is,

```
define(function() { 

    var label = {
        "name" : "Name",
        "age" : "Age",
        "location" : "Location"
    }

    var message = {
        "save": "data saved",
        "update": "data updated"
    }

   return {
        label: label,
        message: message
    };

});
```

I will use this obj in my module wherever applicable, like fileName.label.name that will print "Name" in desired place.

like that if a user change the language from english to french(fr) I will get the data from fr.js, which looks like something below:

```
var label = {
        "name" : "****",  [*** - something in french]
        "age" : "***",
        "location" : "***"
    }
```

so fileName.label.name will print the french text.

Here, I'm struck with converting/translating those en file to french and other languages.

I would like to know is there a tool which can translate files and generate desired language , and there will be N number of modules if there's a generalized way to translate would be grateful like give a path of locale files and the tool will give the dedsired op.

Comment: Do you want a tool that shows the english sentences to a persons and this person then can enter the translation for the given language or do you want a fully automated process to translate the sentences?

Comment: something like you have a file which have all English strings/objects, then that tool will automate the file and regenerate those strings to desired language

Comment: While automatic translations became better in the last years (like [deepl.com](https://www.deepl.com/translator)) they are still far away from being usable in an automated process. So you should either use a set of already existing translations, or let them translate by a person.

Comment: @t.niese do you know any API's to translate English string to some other language.